# Android Studio 4.2: Not able to generate Java Doc comments

Tags: android, android-studio, javadoc

I want to generate Java Doc comments.
While generating via. Tools->Generate JavaDoc, I am getting below error:

```
error: option --boot-class-path not allowed with target 11
```

I have used JAVA 1.8 in compile options in build.gradle:

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

Any help or guidance will be well appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm that you have Java 11 installed on your machine? If that is right can you check what have you set as **default** java version? If it is Java 11 change it to 8 and see if that works.

Comment: @StoyanMilev Thanks for the reply. Actually in compiler.xml of Android Studio,  bytecodeTargetLevel target="11" was there. By changing it to 1.8, issue got resolved.